I would like to know why this API takes 10 seconds
I'm trying to measure time when loading data using jpa and mysql in spring boot.
Product.java
@Entity
@ToString
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Table(name = "tbl_product")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long pno;
    private String pname;
    private int price;
    private String pdesc;
    private boolean delFlag;
    private Long categoryNum;

    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime date;

    @Builder.Default
    private Long viewCount= Long.valueOf(0);

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private User seller;
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Builder.Default
    private List<ProductImage> imageList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void changePrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void changeDesc(String desc) {
        this.pdesc = desc;
    }

    public void changeName(String name) {
        this.pname = name;
    }

    public void addImage(ProductImage image) {
        image.setOrd(this.imageList.size());
        imageList.add(image);
    }

    public void addImageString(String fileName) {
        ProductImage productImage = ProductImage.builder()
                .fileName(fileName)
                .build();
        addImage(productImage);
    }

    public void clearList() {
        this.imageList.clear();
    }

    public void setSeller(User seller) {
        this.seller = seller;
    }
}

ProductImage.java
@Embeddable
@Getter
@ToString
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ProductImage {
    private String fileName;

    private int ord;

    public void setOrd(int ord){
        this.ord = ord;
    }
}

ProductController.java
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/api/products")
@Log4j2
@Tag(name = "Product", description = "Product API")
public class ProductController {
    private final ProductService productService;

    private final CustomFileUtil fileUtil;


    @GetMapping("/search")
    public ResponseEntity<?> searchProducts(@RequestParam String query) {
        try {
            List<ProductDTO> products = productService.searchProducts(query);
            log.info(products);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(products);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

ProductService.java
public interface ProductService {
    List<ProductDTO> searchProducts(String query);
}

ProductServiceImpl.java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {
    private final ProductRepository productRepository;

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public List<ProductDTO> searchProducts(String query) {
        List<Product> products = productRepository.findByPnameContainingIgnoreCase(query);

        List<ProductDTO> dtoList = products.stream().map(el -> entityToDTO(el)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return dtoList;
    }


    private ProductDTO entityToDTO(Product product) {
       ProductDTO productDTO = ProductDTO.builder()
                .pno(product.getPno())
                .pname(product.getPname())
                .pdesc(product.getPdesc())
                .price(product.getPrice())
                .seller(product.getSeller().getUserName())
                .viewCount(product.getViewCount())
                .categoryNum(product.getCategoryNum())
                .build();

        List<ProductImage> imageList = product.getImageList();

        if(imageList == null || imageList.size() == 0 ){
            return productDTO;
        }

        List<String> fileNameList = imageList.stream().map(productImage -> productImage.getFileName()).toList();

        productDTO.setUploadFileNames(fileNameList);

        return productDTO;
    }
}

ProductRepository.java
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
    List<Product> findByPnameContainingIgnoreCase(String query);
}

If the product name is "Product 1", "Product 2", "Product 3"... "Product 1000" and search for the word "product" as a keyword, all products will be returned in List format in 10 seconds.



However, if I use the findall() function on the Product it takes less than 1 seconds in total.
I would like to know why this API takes 10 seconds.
I also measured the time using mysql workbench and postman, but it took less than 2 seconds in total.
mysql workbench
select * from product_image_list; <- Duration 16ms
select * from tbl_product; <- Duration 17ms
I solved the problem through fetch join, but even after searching, I couldn't find why it took 10 seconds.

Remove the log.info... That will call the toString on each product, which due to the @ToString will automatically retrieve all fields even the lazy ones. Basically don't use @ToString (or even worse @Data) for @Entity classes. Another thing is that you are basically writing a query which doesn't take into account the eager loading (those only help when using findById) so it will issue additional queries for each related entity it will need. To make it really fast, don't return the product but write a dedicated query that you can directly map to the dto you need.

Do you have an index on the pname column in the database?

No, I did not add a index column for pname.
